# Raspberry ISO mount via sshfs fails

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, mount, sshfs

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

Background: I want to mount very big ISOs to my raspberry via sftp.
If I try to mount the iso from a local folder, for example Downloads\2005-2010.iso it works perfect. But if I try to mount the ISO from a mounted sshfs folder, it fails. I also tryed to change the permission to 777 (only for testing) to the mounted ftp folder, but no  success.

I using "sshfs" to mount my ftp webhosting folder. (Works perfect)

The Output is different to the following statements:

1. Statement

> sudo mount /home/pi/isomount/2005-2010.iso  /home/pi/medien/2005-2010/

1.1 Output

> mount: /home/pi/medien/2005-2010: **cannot mount** /home/pi/isomount/2005-2010.iso **read-only.**

2. Statement

> sudo mount -o loop /home/pi/isomount/2005-2010.iso  /home/pi/medien/2005-2010/

2.1 Output

> mount: /home/pi/medien/2005-2010/: **failed to setup loop device for** /home/pi/isomount/2005-2010.iso.

Any idears what I can do to mount this .iso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, this worked :

```
sudo bash
# Now in root
mkdir /tmp/iso
mount /home/pi/isomount/2005-2010.iso /tmp/iso
```

More details

```
~# cd /home/ubuntu/dev
/home/ubuntu/dev# df -k .
Filesystem             1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
User@remotehost:dev 487213052 380126780 107086272  79% /home/ubuntu/dev <-- sshfs mounted
/home/ubuntu/dev# ls -l ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
-rwx------ 1 197609 197121 3071934464 Dec 28 10:44 ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
/home/ubuntu/dev# mount ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso /tmp/iso
mount: /tmp/iso: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.
/home/ubuntu/dev# ls -ltr /tmp/iso
total 101
lr-xr-xr-x 1 root root     1 Aug 19 11:59 ubuntu -> .
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 Aug 19 11:59 preseed
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 Aug 19 11:59 pool
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 Aug 19 11:59 dists
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 Aug 19 12:01 install
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 Aug 19 12:01 casper
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 Aug 19 12:01 boot
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 Aug 19 12:01 EFI
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 34816 Aug 19 12:01 isolinux
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 53487 Aug 19 12:03 md5sum.txt
```

My sshfs mount options in /etc/mtab :

```
User@remotehost:dev /home/ubuntu/dev fuse.sshfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1001,group_id=1001,allow_other 0 0
```

Comment: Hi, do you use sshfs to mount the FTP folder where the ISO is stored? When I use the ISO from a lokal storage it also works for me, but this is not what I want.

Comment: @Seb Added more details

Comment: I add the switch  "-o allow_other"  to the sshfs mount statement and now I can easly mount the ISO from the ftp server. Perfect thanks for the tip @Philippe